# How can I transfer photos from my Android Jelly Bean device to laptop while preserving the original timestamp?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, file-transfer

I want to transfer my photos from Samsung galaxy Pocket Neo gt-s5312(4.1.2,Jelly Bean) to Laptop with out changing Time Stamp (File creation date and modified date).I tried MTP,Bluetooth,wifi,mail attachment,adb pull and GoodSync  but no use.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: How about zipping them on your device and mailing then to yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get your photos transferred to your laptop is directly using USB cable to copy and paste them there.

Comment: The questioner said he already tried using MTP (i.e. the protocol it uses when you plug it in with a USB cable), and that doesn't work to preserve the timestamp.